# Can I add other businesses to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

In my local suburb the business owners aren't very tech savvy so I'm wondering if it's possible for me to add their businesses to Google Maps on their behalf.

Is it possible, and if so, how would I go about it? I've skimmed through the [Google Maps help](https://support.google.com/maps/?hl=en#topic=3092444) and it seems to focus on businesses adding in their own information.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is bound to be no if only because otherwise the unscrupulous would be assigning their own telephone number to their competitors' listings etc, but the most specific denial I can find is:

> Only business owners or authorized representatives may verify and manage their business information on Google My Business.

from [here](http://localu.org/blog/rules-for-google-plus-local-for-business-listings/).

Comment: Thanks. The authorized representatives term may be adequate for what I need though! I'll explore that idea further.